# PHP auto-incude from a folder

Tags: php, plugins

I want to create a system which will include any `.php` file from a folder, similar to `wordpress\plugins` folder. Preferably drag and drop.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: http://php.net/glob, http://php.net/foreach

Answer (score 1):

Question is not clear...

- read the folder files
- scroll through the files found
- if PHP - include it

Comment: i only want to include it if its php. thats all

Comment: And that's what I suggest: "if PHP - include it". When you read files from folder - filenames will have extensions. Check filename. If last 3 chars are 'php' - include the file

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function scandir2($dir)
{
    $out = array();
    if (is_dir($dir))
    {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir))
        {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
            {
                if ($file == '.' or $file == '..') continue;

                if (!is_dir($dir . '/'. $file))
                {
                    $out[] = $dir . '/' . $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    sort($out);
    return $out;
}

$i=scandir2(".");
foreach($i as $name)
{
    if(strstr($name ,'.php'))
    include($name);
}
?>
```

this code scan directory and include php files ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do that:

```
foreach (glob("/path/*.php") as $filename) {
    include $file;
}
```

The `glob()` function returns an array of all `.php` files on the specified path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it...

```
<?php

$dirPath = '/path/to/files';
if ($handle = opendir($dirPath)) {

    /* loop over files in directory */
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {        

        /* find extension */
        $ext = substr($entry,-3);
        $ext = strtolower($ext);

        /* include file if extension is PHP */
        if ($ext === 'php') {
            include_once($dirPath .'/'. $entry);
        } //if

    } //if


    closedir($handle);
} //if
```

Note that there is several security concerns and possibly performance concerns.